# How to encode dates in a JSON response in PHP like '/Date(1365004652303-0500)/'?

Tags: php, json

I see that `.NET` can encode the dates like `/Date(1365004652303-0500)/` when it generate the JSON response for a RestFull API response (for example read [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx)).

My question is how can I generate the same output for my date properties inside an object when I use `json_encode` function to encode that object in the PHP.

I don't mean how to do it with an algorithm. I know how to write the algorithm! I would like to do it in a way that the front-end could understand this property is a date! I don't want to transfer it as a simple text!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format

Comment: How can I force the `json_encode` to generate the requested format from Date objects? I cannot find a clear answer there. I don't care about human readable dates!
I want machine recognizable dates in my API response.

Comment: Somebody there said `What .NET does is a non-standard hack/extension.` So does it mean it is not a good idea to have such a format??

Comment: JSON support 6 types on data: `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `null`, `object`, `array`. No `date` type for you, sir :)

Comment: Yes, It seems this is not a good format in general.